# Functional Equivalent to Python Statement Logic

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to find the functional equivalent of logic statements in Python (e.g. and/or/not). I thought I had found them in the `operator` module, but the behavior is remarkable different.

For example, the `and` statement does the behavior I want, whereas `operator.and_` seems to requir an explicit type comparison, or else it throws a TypeError exception.

```
>>> from operator import *
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> and_(A(), True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'instance' and 'bool'
>>> A() and True
True
```

Is there something like the `operator` module, but containing functions that match the behavior of Python's statement logic exactly?

Comment: Why not roll your own? `def and_(p1,p2): return p1 and p2`

Comment: @Bryan: Easy, yes - but OP is doing it right(tm) and asking for the existing wheel before reinventing it (even if it only takes a few seconds).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions `operator.and_` and `operator.or_` are the equivalent of the **bit-wise** "and" function and "or" function, respectively.  There are no functions representing the `and` and `or` operators in `operator`, but you can use the built-ins `any()` and `all()` instead.  They will take a single sequence as argument, but you can simply pass a tuple of two entries to use them as binary operators.

Note that it is impossible to match the logic of `and` and `or` exactly with any function you call.  For example

```
False and sys.stdout.write("Hello")
```

will never print anything, while

```
f(False, sys.stdout.write("Hello"))
```

will always print the output, regardless how `f()` is defined.  This is also the reason they are omitted from `operator`.